# Embedded macro to view all filtered records in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I'm a newish user to Access and I'm having trouble using a button to view a set of records based on a query with several criteria. I am creating a database to house employee quality assessments. As seen below the subform pulls four records.  [view of data showing 4 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQSRu.jpg) when I click the circled button it takes me to the expanded view of the record that is selected on the subform. Once I get there however I only have the one record. [expanded view of a single record with no other records available on the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o9iV.jpg) I would like to be able to browse back and forth between all four records rather than closing the form and going back to the summary.  Hopefully someone can point me at what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are probably opening the second form filtered to the record selected. Without seeing the code you are using, I would suspect you need to alter that behavior.

Comment: Here is my macro. I know that it is indeed filtered to the ID, I'm just not sure how to make that include the other 3 records. [IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/2cxjnuo.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Okay so change that to a filter that is UserID / name , the same as is pulled in via your subform.

Comment: Perfect. For those who are new at this like me I set the Filter Name field to the name of the query I based the Subform summary page on and removed the Where Condition,  and that worked great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so it can be marked as answered - Change the record source of the expanded view form to match the calling sub form's record source.